# footer call back happening after afterStep call

Tags: spring-batch

My spring batch writer implements footer call back and step execution listener as below:

```
public class MyItemWriter implements ItemWriter<MyBean>, FlatFileFooterCallback, StepExecutionListener, ItemStream
```

The class is having a private String property.

```
private String one;
```

My footerCallback and afterStep methods are as below:

```
public void writeFooter(Writer writer) throws IOException {
this.one = "this is a test";
}

public ExitStatus afterStep(StepExecution stepExecution) {
File file = new File("myFile");
try {
      FileUtils.write(file, this.one);          
 } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
   } 
  return null;
}
```

As clear, I am setting the property string one in footerCallBack and then using it in afterStep method.

However, I am getting null value written in the file.

On debugging I found that afterStep method is getting called before writeFooter.

But isn't it wrong ?  Shouldn't step complete only after even the footerCallBack is over ?

Comment: Without looking into details i follow your conclusion, please create a Jira

Comment: @MichaelLange: Created issue 1892 in Jira... thanks..